# matplotlib get text box anchor

Tags: matplotlib, textbox

for legend boxes in matplotlib it is possible to set the anchor point on the canvas and the anchor point of the legend box itself with the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), '-o', label = 'example')
leg = plt.legend(loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (0, 0))
#                       ^^^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^
#                       |                              \==> anchor on the canvas
#                       \==> anchor point of the legend box
```

though I can set the anchor point on the canvas for text boxes, I can't set the anchor point of the box. Is there a simple way to do that?